# Error Using BBQ function in BCDating Package

Tags: r

Receiving the following error using the BBQ function in the BCDating R package and can't seem to pinpoint why:

> Error in if (bcp[i] - bcp[i - 1] < mincycle) { : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

In order to recreate this:

```
library(readxl)
library(BCDating)
library(dplyr)
url <- "https://www.philadelphiafed.org/-/media/research-and-data/regional- 
economy/indexes/coincident/coincident-revised.xls?la=en"
destfile <- "coincident-revised.xls"
download.file(url, destfile, mode = 'wb')
coincident <-read_excel("coincident-revised.xls")
coincident2<- coincident %>% 
 select(-Date) %>% 
 mutate_if(is.character,as.numeric) %>% 
 na.omit()
attach(coincident2)
```

This error is only occurring for Georgia (column GA). This can be seen by transforming both FL and GA into time series, then running BBQ on them. FL works while GA has an error:

```
fcoincident<- ts(FL, start=c(1979, 4), frequency=12)
mod3<- BBQ(fcoincident, mincycle = 12, minphase = 6, name= main)
gcoincident<- ts(GA, start=c(1979, 4), frequency=12)
mod2<- BBQ(gcoincident, mincycle = 12, minphase = 6, name= main)
```

Any help understanding/rectifying this error would be appreciated!

Comment: I wanted to have a look at this but the URL you provided leads to *The page or file you requested was not found.* message. I would suggest that you consider providing some sample data, with use [`dput`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/dput) function or any other convenient manner. It will be easier for folk to engage with your question.

Comment: @Konrad following that URL will give that message, but that code will still download the file. If you would prefer the URL where you can click to download it is [here](https://www.philadelphiafed.org/research-and-data/regional-economy/indexes/coincident). I'm not familiar with dput, but I didn't think I was able to attach a file on Stack Overflow. (I am new though, so I may be incorrect about this). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update: This can be solved by reducing the minphase input into the function. This only works in certain situations though. If you are having trouble using the Bry-Boschan Method, I would recommend writing code to use the non-parametric algorithm in [Metro Business Cycles](https://files.stlouisfed.org/files/htdocs/wp/2014/2014-046.pdf) (especially useful if you're doing State or MSA level analysis).